# How to fetch only Code which is within the Country code

Tags: xml, api, soap, groovy, xml-parsing

I have used Xmlparser().ParseText Need to fetch only Country code eg:Canada from the output can anyone help me on this

```
def parser = new XmlParser()
def doc = parser.parseText(response.toString());
println(doc)
```

Got the below output:

```
Envelope[attributes={}; value=[Body[attributes={}; value=[GetCountriesAvailableResponse[attributes={}; value=[GetCountriesAvailableResult[attributes={}; value=[CountryCode[attributes={}; value=[Code[attributes={}; value=[Canada]], Description[attributes={}; value=[Canada]]]], ]]]]
```

Comment: What's the XML you're parsing?

Comment: Show the xml file please